# It's a good idea for somebody to do something?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> It's a good idea to do something

We use this for giving someone advice about what they should do

My question is:
can we add a prepositional phrase (e.g. for + an object pronoun) to be specific about the person we think should do that thing? Or it's a fixed expression and it's used just for you and not other persons?

e.g.

> It's a good idea for us/you/him/them to leave the car outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you are asking about

> It's a good idea **for you** to leave the car outside.
>   It's a good idea **for him** to leave the car outside.
>   It's a good idea **for them** to leave the car outside.
>   It's a good idea **for us** to leave the car outside.

are grammatically correct and specifically qualifies whom the idea is good **for**.

Other prepositions which can be used as qualifiers are

> It's a good idea **in general** to leave the car outside.
>   It's a good idea, **between you and me**, to leave the car outside.
>   It's a good idea **over time** to leave the car outside.
>   It's a good idea **before anything else** to leave the car outside.

Comment: Just a quick clarification: that list of other prepositions is just a sample, and not an exhaustive list. There are many others.